# Where is Homebrew's doctor.rb?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I need to change some configuration for the `brew doctor` tool and by surfing the web I learned that this can be done by editing the `doctor.rb` file and adding some custom code inside it.

The **problem** is that when I run

```
locate doctor.rb
```

I get an output like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/[...]/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/doctor.rb
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/[...]/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/doctor.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/[...]/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/doctor.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/doctor.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/[...]/doctor.rb
```

So, which `doctor.rb` file should I edit to customize the configuration?

Comment: Can you share the link for the article that outlines the instruction to edit `doctor.rb`?

Comment: @NimeshNeema [this](https://superuser.com/questions/656578/warning-unbrewed-dylibs-were-found-in-usr-local-lib/656581?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question has a very good answer, the one by Brian Carlson, where he suggests to edit file `doctor.rb` to add a "white list" to avoid warnings about some "unbrewed" dynamic libraries. He suggests to find the file using `locate doctor.rb` but as you say in my question this my provide multiple answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Update to incorporate Apple Silicon Mac**:

The file that you are looking to edit should be present in Homebrew installation directory, which generally is `/usr/local`, on Intel Macs and `/opt/homebrew` on Apple Silicon Macs.

From your shared `locate` output, the one matching the criterion is:

- `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb` on Intel Macs.
- `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb` on Apple Silicon Macs.

Comment: Many thanks @NimeshNeema but, based on what you say, the last three lines in my answer would all be suitable to be the right one, what do you think?

Comment: `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/cli/doctor.rb` corresponds to Homebrew cask. The last one, i.e. `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/[...]/doctor.rb` is not a part of Homebrew proper. So my answer still stands the same.

Comment: Many thanks for the precious information about Homebrew cask, I thought `cask` was just a command-line argument for the command-line `brew` tool.

Comment: Note that on Apple Silicon, Homebrew installs to a different location.  The path is currently `/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb` for M1/M2 macs.